# How to check whether this/any folder contains any mp4 file or not in android using cordova?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, filepath

Lets Suppose I have a folder in android, it may be in internal or external storage:
"VIKAS KOHLI" folder and I want to check in "VIKAS KOHLI" whether there is any .mp4 file or not.
Then how can I check this by using cordova?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the folder and see :P . hey man! here we can solve your problem with at least what you tried. Your question is make me create a new project :(

Comment: I have to give user a browse button in which he browses a directory. Then after that I have to check that selected directory contains mp4 files or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the File plugin. Some basic example code here:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DIR_FULL_PATH, function(dirEntry) {
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    console.log(dirEntry);

    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
});

function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    //Here you can check the entries ofject for the file name and do stuff    
    console.log('En - ', entries[i]);
    }
}
function fail(error) {
    console.log("Failed to list directory contents: ", error);
}
```

Reference to the file plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: Yes I read about this. But I am stucking in DIR_FULL_PATH, How this directory path I get and also I just to check file of particular extension

Comment: https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app This link uses Ionic, but you may be able to make it work for you perhaps?